# import scala.swing._ in eclipse giving an error that it is not a member of package scala

Tags: eclipse, swing, scala

Does anybody have any experience with trying to get swing to work in eclipse, I can import it fine into scala using the command line interface, but when i try and use it in an eclipse scala project I get the following error:

import scala.swing._

"object swing is not a member of package scala"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: scala-swing has been split out into a separate repository https://github.com/scala/scala-swing . Have you added it to your library dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are missing the library (as Rüdiger said, it is a separate dependency now), you can find how to add it to your build system here (for Scala 2.11):

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang.modules|scala-swing_2.11|1.0.1|bundle

Look under "Dependency Information", e.g. for sbt if you use that.